# Mootools sortables, disable events on the sortable elements when dragging and dropping

Tags: mootools, sortables

http://jsfiddle.net/4byth/

```
var mySortables = new Sortables('#sortable',
{
    clone:true,
    revert:true,
    opacity:1

});
```

I am using sortables to allow users to rearrange slides by dragging a span containing the thumbnail of the slide to a new position. These elements are inline.

There is an A tag surrounding the image which when clicked lets the user edit that slide.

In some cases the link is activated when you release the sortable element, I haven't quite been able to work out when this happens.

My question is, is it possible to disable the link until the drop is complete and then renable it, or should I just use a different approach to displaying them and perhaps add onclick events to the span elements which I can remove/readd more easily.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the start,complete events to set a flag and only if this flag is false when clicking on the anchor - enable the editing.

```
var is_dragging;
var mySortables = new Sortables('#sortable',
{
    clone:true,
    revert:true,
    opacity:1,
    onStart: function(){

      is_dragging = true; 
    },

    onComplete: function(){
        is_dragging = false;   
    }

});
    function onClickAnchor(){
       if(!is_dragging){
         //do stuff
       }
    }
```

Comment: thank you I will try that and control the anchor tag with my JS. Thanks